# 'ReferenceError: httpResponse is not defined' When parsing JSON response of Parse httpRequest

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, promise

My promise statement pings eBay multiple times, each time with the properties of a `matchCenterItem` as the parameters. When it has run through all the instances, I want it to then send all the responses over to my iOS app.

My attempt to do this in `response.success` results in an error stating `httpResponse is not defined`, even though I do define it beforehand.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("MatchCenterTest", function(request, response) {
    //defines which parse class to iterate through
    var matchCenterItem = Parse.Object.extend("matchCenterItem");
    var query = new Parse.Query(matchCenterItem);
    var promises = [];
    //setting the limit of items at 10 for now
    query.limit(10);
    query.find().then(function(results) {
        for (i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
            url = 'http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1';
            //push function containing criteria for every matchCenterItem into promises array
              promises.push(function() {
                return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
                  url: url,
                  params: {
                      'OPERATION-NAME' : 'findItemsByKeywords',
                      'SERVICE-VERSION' : '1.12.0',
                      'SECURITY-APPNAME' : '*APP ID GOES HERE*',
                      'GLOBAL-ID' : 'EBAY-US',
                      'RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT' : 'JSON',
                      'REST-PAYLOAD&sortOrder' : 'BestMatch',
                      'paginationInput.entriesPerPage' : '3',
                      'outputSelector=AspectHistogram&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value(0)' : results[i].get('itemCondition'),
                      'itemFilter(1).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(1).value' : results[i].get('maxPrice'),
                      'itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(1).paramValue' : 'USD',
                      'itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(2).value' : results[i].get('minPrice'),
                      'itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue' : 'USD',
                      //'itemFilter(3).name=LocatedIn&itemFilter(3).Value' : request.params.itemLocation,
                      'itemFilter(3).name=ListingType&itemFilter(3).value' : 'FixedPrice',
                      'keywords' : results[i].get('searchTerm'),
                  }
                });
              });
        }
        Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
          var eBayResults = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
          for (i=0; i<eBayResults.length; i++)
          {
            console.log(eBayResults[i]); // So you can see what the response 
                                     // looks like for each httpRequest that was made
          }
          // and by the way if this is the end of your function, then here you can call
          response.success(eBayResults);
        }, function(err) {
                  console.log('error!');
                  response.error();
           });
    });
});
```

Comment: You're using `httpResponse.text`, but you've never declared a variable `httpResponse`. Maybe it should be `.then(function(httpResponse))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this fragment to

```
Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(httpResponse) {
      var eBayResults = JSON.parse(httpResponse.text);
      for (i=0; i<eBayResults.length; i++)
      {
        console.log(eBayResults[i]); // So you can see what the response 
                                 // looks like for each httpRequest that was made
      }
```

assuming that your promise object return httpResponse.

Comment: Ahh I see. Making this change is now giving me a strange error stating `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in <unknown file>:1 (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.19)`.

Comment: And when I try to display httpResponse.text by itself without parsing, it gives me a value of `null`.

Comment: @Ghobs try adding more parameters to response, `.then(function(a,b) {`

Comment: So `httpResponse` would be the `b` in this case? What would be `a`?